# Python Selenium send_keys function sends part of text

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Python Selenium with chromedriver for automated testing.
Below is the code sample:

```
        inputElement.send_keys(2356785)
        try:
            print("Trying using ENTER")
            submit = driver.find_element_by_id('button_id')
            submit.send_keys("\n")
        except Exception as e:
            print("--TRYING using CLICK")
            driver.find_element_by_id('button_id').click()
```

The problem with the code is that some random part of the text is entered in the input element rather than the full text.

Things already tried:

- Sending the digits one by one.
- Adding delay before and after the `send_keys()` function.
- Typecasted the number into string.

Comment: can You post a url?

Comment: Try changing the chrome driver version - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1771

Comment: This is an internal tool, so I can't share the url @ZarakiKenpachi

Comment: Can you share the screenshot ?

Comment: @GauravNeema try to clear() the inputElement or click() into textfield before sending keys

Comment: Tried this, still same issue. @ZarakiKenpachi

Comment: @GauravNeema then try using WebDriverWait till input element is loaded or just set time.sleep(3) before sending keys

Comment: I tried this solution too and I also mentioned this in question. @ZarakiKenpachi

Comment: @GauravNeemawhat can you post html line that contains input tag

Comment: Solved this: Used ```driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('number_id').setAttribute('value','"+str(num)+"')")``` instead of ```send_keys()```

Comment: Have you tried `inputElement.send_keys("2356785")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        inputElement.send_keys("2356785") #Notice how i am sending the input as a string instead of int
    try:
        print("Trying using ENTER")
        submit = driver.find_element_by_id('button_id')
        submit.send_keys("\n")
    except Exception as e:
        print("--TRYING using CLICK")
        driver.find_element_by_id('button_id').click()
```

Maybe using a string instead of the int could solve your problem